# Problem in using quotes : PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have this PL/SQL query:

```
  DECLARE
  v_table_owner VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_USER';
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_TABLE';
  v_view_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'PARTITION_TABLE_VIEW';
  BEGIN 
  -- Create a view to associate partitions with tables  
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ' || v_view_name || ' AS 
  SELECT aip.index_owner, aip.index_name, aip.partition_name, ait.table_name 
   FROM all_ind_partitions aip 
    JOIN all_tab_partitions ait ON aip.index_owner = ait.table_owner  AND aip.index_name = ait.table_name 
WHERE aip.status = ''UNUSABLE''';
-- Rebuild unusable indexes for the specified table  
FOR rec_index IN (SELECT
    owner,
    index_name
FROM
    all_indexes
WHERE
    table_name = ' || v_table_name || '
    AND status = ''UNUSABLE'')   
 LOOP    
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || rec_index.owner || '.' || rec_index.index_name || ' REBUILD';

 END LOOP;
-- Rebuild unusable partitions for the specified table using the view   
  FOR rec_partition IN (SELECT index_owner,index_name,partition_name
FROM
    ' || v_view_name || '
WHERE
    table_name = ' || v_table_name || ') 
    LOOP 
    DECLARE 
    v_sql VARCHAR2(1000);
   BEGIN v_sql := 'ALTER INDEX ' || rec_partition.index_owner || '.' || rec_partition.index_name || ' REBUILD PARTITION ' || rec_partition.partition_name;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING v_table_name; -- Bind the variable
   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN -- Handle exceptions, e.g., log or ignore
   NULL;
  END;
  END LOOP;
  END;
```

The problem is that when I run the query receive this error:

```
   Error report -
   ORA-06550: line 25, column 24:
   PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
   ORA-06550: line 18, column 23:
   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
   ORA-06550: line 36, column 9:
   PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name
   ORA-06550: line 31, column 27:
   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
   *Action:
```

I think it is because of using wrong quotes, I know to escape a single quote within the string, must use two single quotes (''). I used that but it didn't work either.

Would you please guide me how to solve the problem?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
FOR rec_index IN (SELECT
    owner,
    index_name
FROM
    all_indexes
WHERE
    table_name = ' || v_table_name || '
    AND status = ''UNUSABLE'')
```

Does not use a string literal for the SQL statement so `' || v_table_name || '` is a single string literal and not a concatenation and `''UNUSABLE''` is invalid syntax.

You want:

```sql
  FOR rec_index IN (
    SELECT owner,
           index_name
    FROM   all_indexes
    WHERE  table_name = v_table_name
    AND    status = 'UNUSABLE'
  )
```

Similarly:

```sql
  FOR rec_partition IN (SELECT index_owner,index_name,partition_name
FROM
    ' || v_view_name || '
WHERE
    table_name = ' || v_table_name || ')
```

Tries to dynamically use `v_view_name` and you can see from the syntax mark-up above that it is treating `' || v_view_name || '` and `' || v_table_name || '` as string literals and not concatenation, this should be:

```sql
  DECLARE
    v_cur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_owner ALL_IND_PARTITIONS.INDEX_OWNER%TYPE;
    v_name  ALL_IND_PARTITIONS.INDEX_NAME%TYPE;
    v_pname ALL_IND_PARTITIONS.PARTITION_NAME%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    OPEN v_cur FOR 'SELECT index_owner,
                           index_name,
                           partition_name
                    FROM   ' || v_view_name || '
                    WHERE  table_name = ''' || v_table_name || '''';
    LOOP
      FETCH v_cur INTO v_owner, v_name, v_pname;
      EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
      BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || v_owner || '.' || v_name || ' REBUILD PARTITION ' || v_pname;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);
      END;
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

*Note: You do not appear to declare a bind variable in the final `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement so it is not clear why you think you need a `USING` clause.*

This gives the code:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_table_owner VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_USER';
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_TABLE';
  v_view_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'PARTITION_TABLE_VIEW';
BEGIN 
  -- Create a view to associate partitions with tables  
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ' || v_view_name || ' AS 
    SELECT aip.index_owner, aip.index_name, aip.partition_name, ait.table_name 
    FROM   all_ind_partitions aip 
           JOIN all_tab_partitions ait
           ON     aip.index_owner = ait.table_owner
              AND aip.index_name = ait.table_name 
    WHERE  aip.status = ''UNUSABLE''';

  -- Rebuild unusable indexes for the specified table  
  FOR rec_index IN (
    SELECT owner,
           index_name
    FROM   all_indexes
    WHERE  table_name = v_table_name
    AND    status = 'UNUSABLE'
  )   
  LOOP    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || rec_index.owner || '.' || rec_index.index_name || ' REBUILD';
  END LOOP;

  -- Rebuild unusable partitions for the specified table using the view
  DECLARE
    v_cur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_owner ALL_IND_PARTITIONS.INDEX_OWNER%TYPE;
    v_name  ALL_IND_PARTITIONS.INDEX_NAME%TYPE;
    v_pname ALL_IND_PARTITIONS.PARTITION_NAME%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    OPEN v_cur FOR 'SELECT index_owner,
                           index_name,
                           partition_name
                    FROM   ' || v_view_name || '
                    WHERE  table_name = ''' || v_table_name || '''';
    LOOP
      FETCH v_cur INTO v_owner, v_name, v_pname;
      EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
      BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || v_owner || '.' || v_name || ' REBUILD PARTITION ' || v_pname;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);
      END;
    END LOOP;
  END;
END;
/
```

*Note: If any of your dynamic identifiers are in mixed- or lower-case then your query will fail. In this case, you would need to use quoted identifiers.*

You can also simplify it and get rid of the dynamic view:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_table_owner VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_USER';
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_TABLE';
BEGIN 
  -- Rebuild unusable indexes for the specified table  
  FOR rec_index IN (
    SELECT owner,
           index_name
    FROM   all_indexes
    WHERE  table_name = v_table_name
    AND    status = 'UNUSABLE'
  )   
  LOOP    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || rec_index.owner || '.' || rec_index.index_name || ' REBUILD';
  END LOOP;

  -- Rebuild unusable partitions for the specified table using the view
  FOR rec_partition IN (
    SELECT aip.index_owner,
           aip.index_name,
           aip.partition_name
    FROM   all_ind_partitions aip 
           JOIN all_tab_partitions ait
           ON     aip.index_owner = ait.table_owner
              AND aip.index_name = ait.table_name 
    WHERE  aip.status = 'UNUSABLE'
    AND    table_name = v_table_name
  )
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        'ALTER INDEX ' || rec_partition.index_owner || '.' || rec_partition.index_name
          || ' REBUILD PARTITION ' || rec_partition.partition_name;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-C80edJt)

Comment: @MTO, thank you for your complete answer.

Comment: @MTO , the Oracle table has been partitioned on date column. Would you please guide me how it is possible to run the above pl/sql query on the current partition? I want to make all indices for the current partition **unusable** and after loading data, make all of them **rebuild** with the query.

Comment: @M_Gh If you have a new problem, you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @MTO, would you please take a look at the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77402702/6640504? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you buetify your code, you will see, that after `WHERE aip.status = ''UNUSABLE''';` you have source code outside of the string.
But how we should guess, if this code should be inside of the string or outside?
Maybe it should be inside of the string, because you using this strange conctruction for loop:

`WHERE  table_name = ' || v_table_name || '`

This is not possible with regular source code, maybe it should be inside of the string?

Below I put your source code after transforming on the site https://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

```
DECLARE
  v_table_owner VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_USER';
  v_table_name  VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_TABLE';
  v_view_name   VARCHAR2(30) := 'PARTITION_TABLE_VIEW';
BEGIN
  -- Create a view to associate partitions with tables
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW '
  || v_view_name
  || ' AS   SELECT aip.index_owner, aip.index_name, aip.partition_name, ait.table_name    FROM all_ind_partitions aip     JOIN all_tab_partitions ait ON aip.index_owner = ait.table_owner  AND aip.index_name = ait.table_name WHERE aip.status = ''UNUSABLE''';
  -- Rebuild unusable indexes for the specified table
  FOR rec_index IN
  (
         SELECT owner,
                index_name
         FROM   all_indexes
         WHERE  table_name = ' || v_table_name || '
         AND    status = ''unusable'')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX '
    || rec_index.owner
    || '.'
    || rec_index.index_name
    || ' REBUILD';
  END LOOP;
  -- Rebuild unusable partitions for the specified table using the view
  FOR rec_partition IN
  (
         SELECT index_owner,
                index_name,
                partition_name
         FROM   ' || v_view_name || '
         WHERE  table_name = ' || v_table_name || ')
  LOOP
    DECLARE
      v_sql VARCHAR2(1000);
    BEGIN
      v_sql := 'ALTER INDEX '
      || rec_partition.index_owner
      || '.'
      || rec_partition.index_name
      || ' REBUILD PARTITION '
      || rec_partition.partition_name;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING v_table_name; -- Bind the variable
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN -- Handle exceptions, e.g., log or ignore
      NULL;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: still the same error: **ORA-06550: line 17, column 28:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 13, column 10:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 31, column 17:
PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name
ORA-06550: line 28, column 10:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try q-syntax to wrap you lines to avoid confusions with quotes:

```
BEGIN  
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (q'['Hello,' said the child, who didn't like goodbyes.]');  
END;
```

Also you can use paired symbols, like [] () <>, so that any single quotes inside the literal do not need to be doubled.