# How to make all indices of the partitioned Oracle table Unusable for current partition before loading data

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a partitioned Oracle table which is partitioned on date column. I want to make all indices **unusable** before loading data for current partition and after that make them **rebuild**. I use this query to rebuild all indices,local/global:

```
  DECLARE
  v_table_owner VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_USER';
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_TABLE';
  BEGIN 
  -- Rebuild unusable indexes for the specified table  
  FOR rec_index IN (
   SELECT owner,
        index_name
        FROM   all_indexes WHERE  table_name = v_table_name
   AND    status = 'UNUSABLE')   
  LOOP    
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || rec_index.owner || '.' || rec_index.index_name || ' REBUILD';
  END LOOP;
  -- Rebuild unusable partitions for the specified table using the view
 FOR rec_partition IN (
  SELECT aip.index_owner,
       aip.index_name,
       aip.partition_name
   FROM   all_ind_partitions aip 
       JOIN all_tab_partitions ait
       ON     aip.index_owner = ait.table_owner
          AND aip.index_name = ait.table_name 
    WHERE  aip.status = 'UNUSABLE' AND    table_name = v_table_name)
   LOOP
    BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'ALTER INDEX ' || rec_partition.index_owner || '.' || rec_partition.index_name
      || ' REBUILD PARTITION ' || rec_partition.partition_name;
     EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);
    END;
   END LOOP;
```

Also, I use this query to make indices **unusable**:

```
 DECLARE
  v_table_owner VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_USER'; 
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_TABLE';  
  v_partition_date DATE := TO_DATE('2023-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'); 
     BEGIN
     SELECT partition_name INTO v_partition_name FROM all_tab_partitions
      WHERE table_owner = v_table_owner AND table_name = v_table_name AND TO_DATE(partition_name, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = v_partition_date;
 -- Disable indices for the current partition
 FOR rec_index IN (SELECT owner, index_name
      FROM all_indexes
      WHERE table_name = v_table_name)
    LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || rec_index.owner || '.' || 
  rec_index.index_name || ' UNUSABLE PARTITION ' || v_partition_name;
  END LOOP;
 END;
```

The second query has this error:

```
  Error report -
  ORA-06550: line 8, column 8:
  PLS-00201: identifier 'V_PARTITION_NAME' must be declared
  ORA-06550: line 9, column 3:
  PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
  ORA-06550: line 7, column 3:
  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
  ORA-06550: line 20, column 49:
  PLS-00201: identifier 'V_PARTITION_NAME' must be declared
  ORA-06550: line 19, column 5:
  PL/SQL: Statement ignored
  06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
  *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

**Update**
This is the script of creating of the table:

```
  CREATE TABLE test_table
     ("INSERT_DATE_TIME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
        "NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
        "ID" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
        "T_DATE" DATE
     CONSTRAINT "test_table" PRIMARY KEY ("ID", "T_DATE")  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS NOLOGGING    STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645    PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
 TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE) PCTFREE 0 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 1 
MAXTRANS 255 
  COMPRESS BASIC  NOLOGGING 
   STORAGE(
   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
   TABLESPACE "USERS" 
   PARTITION BY RANGE ("T_DATE") INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY')) 
   (PARTITION "SYS_P18549"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2021-03-21 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))   NO INMEMORY SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED PCTFREE 0 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
    COMPRESS BASIC NOLOGGING STORAGE( BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
     TABLESPACE "USERS" );
```

The question is how to run the above queries for current partition,I mean current date?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: In addition to the PL/SQL issues, you'll need to use the syntax `ALTER INDEX abc MODIFY PARTITION xyz UNUSABLE` for that command to work properly. Another thing to consider is whether you should even be doing this. If you load the partition with direct path it will postpone the index maintenance. If further you are using pdml those index partitions will be rebuilt quite quickly. There isn't really any benefit from explicitly disabling and rebuilding them in recent versions. And remember that you can't insert if you have a disabled unique index, just non-unique ones.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want to combine the second part of your first code and use the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement from your second block of code in it:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_table_owner VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_USER';
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'TEST_TABLE';
BEGIN 
  FOR rec_partition IN (
    SELECT aip.index_owner,
           aip.index_name,
           aip.partition_name
    FROM   all_ind_partitions aip 
           INNER JOIN all_tab_partitions ait
           ON     aip.index_owner = ait.table_owner
              AND aip.index_name = ait.table_name 
    WHERE  aip.index_owner =  v_table_owner
    AND    aip.index_name  =  v_table_name
    AND    aip.status      != 'UNUSABLE'
  )
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        'ALTER INDEX ' || rec_partition.index_owner || '.' || rec_partition.index_name
          || ' MODIFY PARTITION ' || rec_partition.partition_name || ' UNUSABLE';
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlerrm);
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*Note: you can exclude all the partitions that are already unusable.*

Comment: Unless it has changed since 19c, OP's syntax should also be corrected: `ALTER INDEX abc MODIFY PARTITION xyz UNUSABLE`

Comment: @MTO, thank you for your answer; but, as I said I want to run the query for the partition which is on current date. Would you please guide me how to do that?

Comment: @M_Gh You have not told us how you have defined your partitions so that part is not answerable.

Comment: @MTO, I thought, saying that the table has partition on the date column is enough. Sorry for that. I have updated the question, would you please take a look at it?  Thanks.